# vb.net Ftp Client - get ftp welcome message (and other messages from FTP Server)

Tags: vb.net, ftp, message, ftpwebrequest

This is my first message here. I noob on programming and I need some help.

I have created a custom ftp application. I'm able to login and download files from the server using ***ftpwebrequest*** method however I can't find the way to read and display ftp's server welcome and other messages.

I need a way to get login failure messages in order to display a warning message on the program interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `FtpWebResponse.BannerMessage` property. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.bannermessage%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The link provided is one part of the complete solution but you have pointed to the right direction. After that it was piece of cake to do it using **StatusCode Property** & **StatusDescription Property**